# How to prevent lazy loading of vulnarable entities in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

My question is rather simple, but I didn't find any clues on the Internet after googling for one hour.

I'm trying to build an Symfony API, but when returning json output, it lazy loads, every relation into the output. While this is not such a big deal (in most cases), its really bad when it does this trick with user information. So everything (password, email, etc.) is displayed.

My question is: Is it possible to mark an entity in doctrine, as protected, so the autoload will not be made, with this entity? In some cases it comes pretty handy but this is a big flaw. If its not possible to mark an entity, is it possible to deactivate it completely, or on an Collection Element?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

```
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;
    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $password;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Profile", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $profile;
```

getters and setters are there.

And there is a Profile class, that is the interface, for all relations. It has an 1to1 relation.

```
class Profile
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="profile", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $user;
```

getters and setters are there to.

```
class Event
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $date;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Profile", inversedBy="ownedEvents")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $profile;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Post::class, mappedBy="event", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $posts;
```

The problem ist, that this profile is loaded, and with it the user...
The following is the controller function. But the serialization is happening in an extra method.

```
public function getUnreactedEvents(): JsonResponse{
        $events = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getManager()
            ->getRepository(Event::class)
            ->getUnreactedEvents($this->profileUtils->getLoggedInProfileFromDatabase()->getId());
        return new JsonResponse($this->eventUtils->eventsToArray($events));
    }
```

here is the to array function. (There is a base class so there are two mathods:

\Utils class:

```
\\Utils class:
    public function eventsToArray($events): array{
        return $this->toArray($events, array("usrEvntSts"));
    }

\\Base class:
   protected function toArray($objects, $fieldsToBeRemoved): array{
        $normalizers = [new DateTimeNormalizer(), new ObjectNormalizer()];
        $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers);

        if(!is_array($objects)){
            $objects = array($objects);
        }

        //normalizes the objects object, for circular references, returns id of the object
        //doctrine comes with own array format
        $objectsArray = $serializer->normalize($objects, 'array', [
            'circular_reference_handler' => function ($object) {
                return $object->getId();
            }
        ]);

        //some keys have to be erased from the event response
        foreach ($objectsArray as $key => $object) {
            if (method_exists($objects[0], "getProfile")){
                /** @var Profile $profile */
                $profile = $objects[$key]->getProfile();
                unset($objectsArray[$key]["profile"]);
                $objectsArray[$key]["profile"]['id'] = $profile->getId();
            }
            foreach ($fieldsToBeRemoved as $field){
                unset($objectsArray[$key][$field]);
            }
        }

        return $objectsArray;
    }
}
```

As you see, my first idea was to just delete the field. But afer I added an new entity relation (posts), which has an owner profile too. The user class is loaded again...

Output:

```
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "xcvxycv",
        "date": "2020-06-28T18:08:55+02:00",
        "public": false,
        "posts": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "date": "2020-06-30T00:00:00+02:00",
                "content": "sfdnsdfnslkfdnlskd",
                "profile": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "user": {
                        "id": 2,
                        "email": "alla",
                        "username": "alla",
                        "roles": [
                            "ROLE_USER"
                        ],
                        "password": "$argon2id$v=19$m=65536,t=4,p=1$a01US1dadGFLY05Lb1RkcQ$npmy0HMf19Neo/BnMqXGwkq8AZKVSCAEmDz8mVHLaQ0",
                        "salt": null,
                        "apiToken": null,
                        "profile": 2
                    },
                    "username": "sdfsdf",
                    "usrEvntSts": [],
                    "ownedEvents": [
                        {
                            "id": 3,
                            "name": "blaaaa",
                            "date": "2020-06-28T18:08:55+02:00",
                            "profile": 2,
                            "public": false,
                            "usrEvntSts": [],
                            "posts": [
                                {
                                    "id": 2,
                                    "date": "2020-06-30T00:00:00+02:00",
                                    "content": "sfdnsdfnslkfdnlskd",
                                    "profile": 2,
                                    "event": 3,
                                    "comments": []
                                }
                            ]
                        },
```

And it goes on and on and on....

Comment: by default only **properties** marked as `public` are serialized, which usually leads to empty serializations, because the default is to make all properties `private` and use (public) setters/getters to modify them. To control json-serialization you can implement the [JsonSerializable](https://www.php.net/JsonSerializable) interface on your entity, for example. Since you don't provide *any code at all* I can't really help you beyond general advice.

Comment: I will edit the question and add the code

Comment: I have added code now. The problem is, that i don't want to edit the methods for every entity...

Comment: it appears you already have some functionality that edits the array output. you could also check for the user key and clean that up too ...

Comment: Yes, but i would like to know, if it is possible to forbid lazy load an Entity completely. Like forbidding to load the User entity forever. So no leaks can happen

Comment: forbidding is not really possible, I mean, how would doctrine determine when to load and when not to load? it all comes down to the ObjectNormalizer, really, since it assumes everything should be normalized, and you could implement a normalizer on top that just returns "null" or whatever for every "User" object it encounters. That might be a very reasonable approach. However, I usually use the JsonSerializable interface to manage all api "exports" or use DTOs, both of which are the approaches that are easy to customize but take some effort

Comment: you could just implement a `asExport()` function on your entities and that one returns the data you actually want to export. That requires additional work whenever you add/modify/remove a property. also, you could ignore attributes: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#ignoring-attributes

Comment: Thanks for your quick response :) I will try that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use [JMSSerializerBundle](https://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle) for that. It is a widely used bundle, also in huge API's. You can exactly configure which properties should be exposed and which not. You can also build groups for exposing properties and use a specific exclusion strategy. Check [the documentation](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies) for further information.

Hint: also check the [Limiting serialization depth](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies#limiting-serialization-depth-of-some-properties) for deep nested objects.